# How to get list of Coupon Codes

Tags: magento-2.1, coupon

Is there any way to get list of all coupon codes which are available to the cart will be displayed in the Cart Page ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that we cannot apply multi coupon codes for cart by default Magento. If we want to get the coupon code base on the quote checkout session:

```
/** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession */
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getCouponCode()
```

In database, we can find it in table `quote` table.

Comment: Hi Khoa TruongDinh. I was trying to achieve like PayTm. Where All the Available Coupons will be displayed and End user can select only one at a time. I was trying to add code in Cart Page. But no Luck.

Comment: Your idea looks good to me. We need to check all applicable sales rules. And then, we get the coupon codes of each sale rule. Let me check.